# How to update a List<T> in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm taking a basic course in C# programming, have never programmed anything before. One of our exercises is to create a program that can rent out movies (i.e. a Videostore) from scratch.

One of my classes contains customers. I need a method where the user of the program can add customers to the first list and a separate method in which to display all customers, containing the newly added customers; or if no customers are added then the original ones.

This is what I´ve done so far:

1. I've created a `List<T>` for the original customers.
2. I have made a method that can add customers to the first list and display them in ONE method.

The problem is that I don´t know how to update the original list of customers with the ones the user adds. If I call the entire method it will obviously (even to me..) return the entire method and make the user add the customers over again. I´ve tried creating two `List<T>`s, but how can I make the original list update to include the customers the user adds?? I managed to call the first list from the second but the reverse doesn't work.

I have tried and tried and tried but I´ve simply run out of ideas! For me even getting this far has been quite the challenge. I thought about giving the whole thing up. Programming is not easy.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very happy!

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Customers
    {
        public Customers()
        {

        }       

        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string Tel
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public List<Customers> CustomerList1()     //Original customers                      
        {
            List<Customers> newCustomer = new List<Customers>
            {
               new Customers
               {
                   Name="A",
                   Tel="1"
               },
               new Customers
               {
                   Name="H",
                   Tel="2"
               },     
            };

            return newCustomer;
        }

        public List<Customers> CustomerList2()    //User adds new customers                                  
        {
            List<Customers> custList = CustomerList1();

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("New Customer");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Name:");
            Console.WriteLine("Tel:");

            List<Customers> addedCustomer = new List<Customers> 
            {
                new Customers               //There is most likely a better way... 
                {
                    Name=Console.ReadLine(),
                    Telephone=Console.ReadLine()
                }          
            };

            custList.AddRange(addedCustomer);

            Console.WriteLine("***************List******************");
            foreach (Customers c in custList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(c.Tel);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("******************************************");

            return addedCustomer;       
        }

        public void CustomerView()  //This method only returns original list
        {                             
            List<Customers> customers = CustomerList1();
            foreach (Customers c in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(c.Tel);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("*******************");
        }

        public void CustomerListAdd()          //This is another method I´ve tried to add
        {                                                       customers..
            List<Customers> customers = CustomerList1();   

            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("New Customer");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------");

            Customers customerAdd = new Customers();
            Console.WriteLine("Name:");
            customerAdd.Name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Tel:");
            customerAdd.Telephone = Console.ReadLine();
            customers.Add(customerAdd);

            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (Customers c in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(c.Tel);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("*******************");
        }
    }   
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry thats what happens when you copy paste things..

Comment: I have a piece of advice for you since you are new to programming: **stick with it**. You are bound to encounter problems and sometimes those problems will even cause you to doubt your decision to ever start trying. But, when you overcome issues (particularly when they become large issues), you will gain a great sense of achievement and satisfaction. Programming becomes enjoyable and you *never* stop learning.

Comment: I will certainly try, I do think programming is fun, especially when things finally work. Sometimes the way there seems very long though.

Answer (score 3):

Make your Customer list class level:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // this is outside of a method, but inside the class
    private List<Customer> customers; 

    public MyClass() 
    {
        // instantiate the customer list inside the constructor
        customers = new List<Customer>();  

        // add a default customer to the list by calling the AddCustomer 
        // method in the constructor.
        AddCustomer(new Customer() { Name = "A", Tel="1" });

        // You can also bypass the AddCustomer method below and just call
        // customers.Add() here instead.  If you have other things you want  
        // to do (like insert the customer into a database, for example)
        // you might want to keep the method like I have below.
    }

    public void AddCustomer(Customer cust)
    {
        // add the customer to the existing list.
        customers.Add(cust); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will try this. One question though: where would I let the user add a customer, inside public void AddCustomer()? I think I actually tried something similar but failed.

Comment: Presumably, Another method outside this class (probably from a UI form somewhere) would be calling the AddCustomer Method and passing it a customer object.

Comment: @user1153537 No your writing code, some really smart people do it and its not hard.

Comment: I´ve tried to change my code to something like what Kyle suggested but now I keep getting StackOverFlowException when I run the program. Could it be something with my properties? How can I check what is wrong? Thanks again for the help.